# Magento: set canUseCheckout to false payment method

Tags: magento, module, payment

I want to disallow some payment methods while checkout onepagecontroller is in indexAction. I've tried like this:

```
$payments = Mage::getSingleton('payment/config')->getAllMethods();
    foreach($payments as $payment)
    {
        $methodinstance = Mage::helper('payment')->getMethodInstance($payment->getCode());
        $methodinstance-> // here i want to set the protected $_canUseCheckout of the specific method class... maybe with __set(var, value) ? 
    }
```

So is there a way to set the canUseCheckout of each method temporarily to false ? Maybe i don't have to use the vars.. maybe theres a function ? 
I didn't find such in the  Model_Abstract Class of payment methods...

Answer (score 1):

you can disable any payment method. for disable payment method, go to payment method model which is you want disable and fine the `protected $_canUseCheckout = true;` please do false this variable and check it.

Comment: Sure, but I want to change this variable while runtime of Magento. So in live mode.

Comment: Maybe you can add a store configuration. Then rewrite the class, override the method canUseCheckout, check the value of store configuration and return a boolean true/false.